# Cannot Create New Configurable Product Magento 1.9.3.8

Tags: configurable-product, magento-1.9.3.8

When attempting to create a new Configurable product we get an incomplete screen for the Product Information i.e. just the left hand menu.

In the Apache error log we see

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getAttributeCode() on
>   null in
>   /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXX.co.uk/httpdocs/magento-1.9.3.8/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Super/Config/Grid.php
>   on line 245, referer:
>   https://www.XXXXXXXXXXX.co.uk/index.php/cgb_mag_admin/catalog_product/new/set/79/type/configurable/key/7f90363b0508fd6c820a0f0ac01074ed/

The code in question reads in the product and gets a list of the attributes but they are empty of detail.  I have created a brand new Attribute Set containing one brand new Attribute and used that to try and create but still fails.

This installation was built with an import of products from a 1.9.2 system. One can view the imported Configurable products and the Associated Products OK.

This installation was a copy up of code and database from a dev system here and it works fine in dev.  I even copied the install back down again to test and it works so there must be some server issue but I cannot work out what it might be.  Any help gratefully accepted.

PHP Version 5.6.36

Comment: do you have any custom module related to product?  did you delete any attribute recently?

Comment: No we don't have any modules that affect products, only payments systems, email and order numbers. No no attributes deleted.